# What is the maximum allowed views in CouchDB

Tags: performance, couchdb

I am building a traffic tracking application. I ended up using CouchDB to store all the traffic log, the application can dynamically create views based on user's query and custom data.

I want to create thousands (or could up to millions) of views.
Is there a limit ? Would too many views impact CouchDB performance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hard limit on the number of views. There are a few things I would recommend though:

First, split up your views among many design documents. My first thought is 1 per user, but you could probably sub-divide them further depending on how many views you actually have.

Views are grouped internally by the design document, which affects when they are rebuilt, where they are stored, etc. Thus, keeping things partitioned off will help prevent 1 user's views from impacting the performance of any other user.

In addition, without regularly compacting your database, each document (including design documents) retains the old copies across different writes, which is one of the reasons CouchDB uses so much disk space. (it trades using more disk space for the ability to write quickly)

Second, be *very* conservative with the values you `emit()` in your views. Avoid things like `emit(key, doc)`. If you emit the entire document in your view, it will be considered part of the view index (which is stored separately from the primary database index) and creates multiple copies of the document. If you need to access the source document in your view, you should use `include_docs=true`.

Depending on exactly the situation, you may want to consider partitioning across multiple databases as well. That may not be possible, depending on how you want to write queries and such, but worth mentioning. If you can partition into databases, that will make creating backups a little easier and may scale better in the long run.

The main point is, CouchDB is **very** flexible, which is one of my favorite things about it, as it puts the power in your hands as a developer.

Comment: There are a lot of factors to consider, so I can't say definitively yes or no. My answer gave a lot of best practices to help you not shoot yourself in the foot. That being said, views are calculated when they are requested, so simply adding lots of views will have no impact on performance. Also, after a view is computed once, it is only adjusted incrementally. CouchDB is pretty well-suited here so I would give it a shot.

Comment: @DominicBarnes You didn't write that explicitly, but I read between the lines of your comment that having multiple views does not impact document write performance (unless a rarely used view is requested during the document write). Did I get it right?

Comment: Write performance should not be affected at all, due to the quick append-only nature of writes. (in addition, views aren't updated on write, they're only updated on read)

Comment: More on updating views on read and grouping by designs: my experiments tell me that when you read a view then *all* the views in the design are updated (not only the requested view). Views from other designs are not updated at that time.